# How to draw trajectory of tracked persons

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to draw a trajectory of tracked persons in opencv using kalman filter.

I'm trying the following code, but the two ending lines are infinite

```
def pipeline(img, tracker, det):
    global cnt
    z_box = det.get_localization(img)
    detections = tracker.update(np.array(z_box))
    prev= []
    cnt = cnt + 1

    for trk in detections:
            trk = trk.astype(np.int32)
            img = helpers.draw_box_label(img, trk, trk[4])  # Draw the bounding boxes on the
            if cnt < 20:
                prev.append(trk)
            else:
                cnt = 0
                prev = []

    for i in range(0,len(prev)-1):
        left1, top1, right1, bottom1 = prev[i][1], prev[i][0], prev[i][3], prev[i][2]
        left2, top2, right2, bottom2 = prev[i+1][1], prev[i+1][0], prev[i+1][3], prev[i+1][2]
        cv2.line(img, pt1=((int(left1 + right1 / 2)), int(top1 + bottom1 / 2)),pt2=(int((left2 + right2) / 2), int((top2 + bottom2) / 2)), color=(255,0,255))
    return img
```

I would like to draw trajectory as the following picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiZ44.png)

According to the comment, I tried this but still didn't work.

```
 for trk in detections:
            trk = trk.astype(np.int32)
            img = helpers.draw_box_label(img, trk, trk[4])  # Draw the bounding boxes on the
            if cnt < 20:
                left2, top2, right2, bottom2 = trk[1], trk[0], trk[3], trk[2]

                prev.append( np.array([int(left2 + right2)/2, int(right2+bottom2)/2]))
            else:
                cnt = 0
                prev = []

    cv2.polylines(img,np.int32([prev]), True, color=(255,0,0))
```

Comment: try to accumulate the box center point coordinates over frames and then use the [cv2.polylines()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/drawing_functions.html#polylines) to plot your array of points. [Example](http://answers.opencv.org/question/75445/how-to-draw-the-curve-line/)

Comment: @GuilhermeVogt I added your idea to the post as code, but still didn't work probably

Comment: You should use the third argument as "False", since you probably don't want a close shape. Why do you empty the "prev" vector instead of just waiting for the next detection? Do you have some images/videos or more concrete data so people can reproduce your error and experiment?